# Erro Stack Underflow e Access Violation Delphi 7

Tags: postgresql, delphi-7, conexão

Estou alterando o banco da minha aplicação Delphi de Firebird para PostgreSQL, porém em alguns pontos da minha aplicação quando estou acessando informações do Banco a seguinte mensagem de erro ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não faço ideia de o que possa estar causando esse erro, se tiverem alguma ideia

Vou adicionar o erro que ocorre também um pouco antes de acessar essa parte da aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando executo a aplicação pelo Delphi, a linha que sempre acusa erro  fica dentro de um arquivo DB.pas no caminho de acesso `C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Source\Vcl` e a linha é a seguinte:

```
procedure TDataSet.Open;
begin
Active := False; //Cursor do erro aponta aqui
end;
```

Comment: Você usa componentes pra arquivo .rav?

Comment: @Sorack Sim, uso sim

Comment: Eu tenho uma ideia de qual o problema. Mas primeiramente vc vai ter que abrir o projeto do componente e recompilar

Comment: @Sorack Quando você diz o projeto está se referindo ao arquivo .pas onde esse componente se encontra?

Comment: Não, ao projeto do componente mesmo. O ideal é que vc atualize-o e recompile

Comment: @Sorack Eu abri o projeto e recompilei, porém o erro continuou ocorrendo, esse "Atualize-o" que você diz seria o que?

Comment: É esse componente que você usa? http://acbr.sourceforge.net/drupal/?q=node/36

Comment: Pior que não, esse erro ocorre em mais de um lugar da minha aplicação mas pelo que vi em nenhum dos lugares se trata de NF

Comment: É, acabei de confirmar aqui que a única vez que eu vi esse problema trocamos o rav por fast report "/

Comment: Pois é, eu revisei aqui agora e realmente não é ligado a _NF'e_ onde ocorre esse erro, mas será que tu consegue me ajudar então quem sabe com o outro Erro que esta ocorrendo o do **"Access Violation"** eu tentei baixar o **CNPack** mas não consegui usá-lo para verificar os acessos ao banco como tu tinha me dito, e esse erro esta ocorrendo direto na aplicação

Comment: Então, o RAVE é para geração de relatório, não necessariamente para nota fiscal. Ele é um componente meio bugado, parece que até a Embarcadero tirou no XE3 ou algo assim pq não funcionava bem. Então talvez é problema do componente mesmo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48131/discussion-between-r-santos-and-sorack).

Comment: @Sorack Sim sim, mas eu não estou o usando o Rave Reports para nota fiscal e sim para gerar relatórios mesmo.
Eu estou preocupado também é com aquele erro de Access Violation, pois tentando encontrar algo que me ajudasse a descobrir por que esse erro estava ocorrendo, vi em alguns fóruns que esse erro é bem difícil de resolver até para programadores em Delphi experientes, imagina pra mim então

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48132/discussion-between-sorack-and-r-santos).

Comment: @Sorack Fiz um teste de tentar colocar o relatório do Rave Reports para ser chamado junto com a execução da aplicação, e passou a dar um erro _Invalid Project Format_, tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do access violation na realidade é o componente [RxLib - Delphi 7](http://www.planetadelphi.com.br/download/870/componente/rxlib-para-delphi-7) que precisava ser instalado.
O erro do Rave Reports deve estar conectado com isso!